# pexports dlltool Syntax error in def file python27.def:0

Tags: python, dlltool

I don't manage to build libpythonX.a.

```
dlltool --dllname "python27.dll" --def "python27.def" --output-lib libpython27.a
```

I get the following error *dlltool.exe: Syntax error in def file python27.def:0*

I have been following the steps on http://sebsauvage.net/python/mingw.html, section 2.

I'm using MinGW32, python 32 bit.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

python27.def is generated by pexports.exe. And the first line of python27.def is "LIBRARY python27.dll". dlltool does not use this line. So you must delete that line.

Comment: Seems like comment more, than answer.

Comment: Not only is it more comment than answer, it is just plain incorrect; dlltool **does** use the `LIBRARY foo.dll` line, but it does seem to consider some patterns for `foo.dll` to be invalid ... for me `LIBRARY python27.dll` is not reported as a syntax error, but `LIBRARY libstdc++-6.dll` is).  If you are seeing this syntax error, you should file a `GNU binutils` bug report, citing the failing library name pattern.